# using multiple table in SQL

Tags: sql

I've got three tables:

`department`, `employee` and `telephone`

**`employee`** has columns `EmpNo`, `Surname`, `Firstname` and `DeptNo`.

**`telephone`** has columns `EmpNo` and `Extension`.

**`department`** has columns `DeptNo` and `DeptName`.

What I am trying to get is the full name, department name and telephone extension.

I think I am almost there but its not working yet.

***My query***

```
SELECT e.Firstname, e.Surname, d.DeptName, t.Extension
FROM employee AS e
INNER JOIN department AS d
INNER JOIN telephone AS t
ON e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo
ON t.EmpNo = e.EmpNo;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To fix your problem, move one of the `ON` clauses before the next `JOIN`

```
SELECT e.Firstname, e.Surname, d.DeptName, t.Extension
FROM employee AS e
INNER JOIN department AS d
  ON e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo
INNER JOIN telephone AS t
  ON t.EmpNo = e.EmpNo;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the claim *"The ON needs to come before the next JOIN"* is not correct. `FROM department AS d INNER JOIN employee AS e INNER JOIN telephone AS t ON t.EmpNo = e.EmpNo ON e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo` is (unusual but) perfectly valid.

Comment: @ypercube - Doesn't this documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) : `join_table:
 table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]` indicate it is optional but must come before another JOIN? (I profess to not be 100% up on my documentation analysis - but that is how I understand it)

Comment: @ypercube - tks - I changed the verbiage. I didn't realize how the syntax allows the JOIN's to be nested, thus allowing all of the `ON` clauses to appear at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The ON clause must follow the JOIN that it is modifying.

So:

`INNER JOIN department d ON e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo`

and

`INNER JOIN telephone t ON t.EmpNo = e.EmpNo;`

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. Join is not in correct format. Use like below

```
SELECT e.Firstname, e.Surname, d.DeptName, t.Extension
 FROM employee AS e
   inner join department AS d
    ON e.DeptNo = d.DeptNo
    inner join telephone AS t
      ON t.EmpNo = e.EmpNo;
```